# React Router route order in multiple pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I try to learn React Router and working with multiple pages. My pages structure is such as below.

```
|_Login
|_Main
  |_Home
  |_Agenda
|_Admin
  |_Main
  |_Settings
```

For this I found an example and that is **worked**

```
<Router>
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/"><LoginPage /></Route>
   
    <Route path='/admin/:path?' exact>             
            <Switch>
                <PrivateRoute path='/admin'><AdminMain/></PrivateRoute>
                <PrivateRoute path='/admin/setting'><AdminSettings/></PrivateRoute>
            </Switch>
    </Route>
    
    <Route>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/login"><LoginPage /></Route>
            <PrivateRoute path="/home"><HomePage /></PrivateRoute>
            <PrivateRoute path="/agenda"><AgendaPage /></PrivateRoute>
        </Switch>
    </Route>
</Switch>
</Router>
```

With this order I can navigate to other pages

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <Link to="/admin">Admin</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
            <Link to="/agenda">Agenda</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
            <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But if I change the order and write admin route under the next route...

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/"><LoginPage /></Route>
    
        <Route>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/login"><LoginPage /></Route>
                <PrivateRoute path="/home"><HomePage /></PrivateRoute>
                <PrivateRoute path="/agenda"><AgendaPage /></PrivateRoute>
            </Switch>
        </Route>
    
    **<Route path='/admin/:path?' exact>             
                <Switch>
                    <PrivateRoute path='/admin'><AdminMain/></PrivateRoute>
                    <PrivateRoute path='/admin/setting'><AdminSettings/></PrivateRoute>
                </Switch>
        </Route>**
    
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

...I can't navigate to admin pages. So is order important for routing? If it is how can I order my routes?

> I found example [here](https://dev.to/xavivzla/react-router-v5-multiple-layouts-4fo4)
> Live demo is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v5-multiple-layout-d5yfw?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/src/router/index.js)

> react-router-dom version 5.2.0

Answer (score 0):

It is because `<Route>` without `path` property will always match. So if you put the `Route` without `path` in first react-router will always go to this route and ignore other route that go after it.